# how to condense several foreach into a single for-each?

Tags: java

I want to concatenate each of these arrays, and then just iterate over the resulting collection.

```
        String[] type = {"school", "home"};
        String[] place = {"tokyo ", " New York"};
        String[] date = {"Sep", "Feb"};


        for(String name: type) {
            Assert.assertFalse(isValid(name));
        }
        for(String name: place) {
            Assert.assertFalse(isValid(name));
        }
        for(String name: date) {
            Assert.assertFalse(isValid(name));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily for-each you showed but maybe you would be interested in something like:

```
Stream.of(type, place, date) //Stream<String[]> example [ [a,b], [c,d] ]
      .flatMap(Stream::of)   //Stream<String>   example [ a, b, c, d ]
      .forEach(name -> Assert.assertFalse(isValid(name));
```

which is similar to

```
for (String[] arr : Arrays.asList(type,place,date)){
    for(String name : arr){
        Assert.assertFalse(isValid(name)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does (stream::of) in flatMap means?

Comment: @alexx here `.flatMap(Stream::of)` is same as calling `.flatMap(array -> Stream.of(array))`. In short earlier we had stream of whole arrays, but thanks to this we now have steam of all elements inside those arrays.

Comment: @alexx If you are asking about `something::otherThing` semantics then that is called *method reference*. It was introduced in Java 8 along with *lambdas* and streams (not to be confused with IO-streams).

Comment: @alexx If you are not familiar with it I would suggest using second example from my answer, IMO it is easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] type = {"school", "home"};
String[] place = {"tokyo ", " New York"};
String[] date = {"Sep", "Feb"};

        Arrays.asList(type, place, date).forEach(item -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                Assert.assertFalse(isValid(item[i]));
            }
        });
```